# Joining multiple answers into one single answer

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, answers

It would be nice if Stack Overflow had a feature to join multiple answers into a single answer

Especially in red hot questions like `c# vs Java` where multiple answers when joined together would make more sense.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that those "red hot questions", by today's standards, are hot enough to get closed.

Comment: Better to join multiple questions into a single question so it could be answered in a definitive way (and maintained, updated when APIs changes, etc.). I can dream...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you find a situation where there are a number of roughly equivalent answers, some of which supply useful details that others lack, then the best thing to do may be to edit the first (time-stamped) answer of the equivalent set to add in those details. Then vote up the one you enhanced.

In my experience, though, if multiple answers to a *technical* question differ, there's usually one that's clearly better than the others, and the other ones are pale imitations (sometimes they really *are* imitations.) Then you can just vote those down.

This doesn't hold on Meta; discussion questions can have multiple "best" answers.

Comment: I've found that some of the better technical questions often end up with a couple of good answers, since there's an audience for both very short, focused answers and those that take the time (and quite a bit of space) to explain some of the underlying concepts to those unfamiliar with them. Of course, getting that depends on having two experts willing to answer the same question without stomping on each others' toes.